# PYTHON remove elements from nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have an array of arrays like this

```
dataSet = [['387230'], ['296163'], ['323434', '311472', '323412', '166282'], ['410119']]
```

I would like to delete element '311472' but do not know how.  I have tried

```
for set in dataSet:
    for item in set:
        if item=="311472":
            dataSet.remove(item)
```

But this does not work

The result should be:

```
[['387230'], ['296163'], ['323434', '323412', '166282'], ['410119']]
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the number of `'311472'` in `dataSet`?

Comment: This is not a set. A set is defined as set(iterator)

Answer (score 9):

Use a nested list comprehension, *retaining* elements instead:

```
dataSet = [[i for i in nested if i != '311472'] for nested in dataSet]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [[i for i in nested if i != '311472'] for nested in dataSet]
[['387230'], ['296163'], ['323434', '323412', '166282'], ['410119']]
```

Your mistake was to remove `item` from `dataSet` instead, but even if you removed the elements from `set` you'd end up with modifying the list in place while iterating over it, which means that further iteration will *skip* elements:

```
>>> lst = ['323434', '311472', '311472', '323412', '166282']
>>> for i in lst:
...     if i == '311472':
...         lst.remove(i)
... 
>>> lst
['323434', '311472', '323412', '166282']
```

That's because the list iterator moves to the next index regardless of later additions or deletions from the list; when removing the first `'311472'` at index 1 the loop moves on to index 2 in a list where everything *past* index 1 has moved down a spot.

Answer (score 4):

You remove from the wrong list. Try `set.remove(item)` instead.

Beware though, that this only works if the data is unique, i.e. you only have a single match for the condition, because you skip an index when you remove inside the loop.

Martijn provides a complete and pythonic solution.

Comment: This won't work; modifying the sequence in place will result in missed elements.

Comment: That's a good point. I still think the main issue was that OP tried to remove from the wrong list, though.

Comment: Sure, but perhaps he tried that first and that didn't work as expected with more complex examples?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the lists in-place, you can use the following code (which I believe is along your original plan):

```
for set in dataSet:
    while "311472" in set:
        set.remove("311472")
```

If there are many *many* repetitions of `"311472"` in a single `set` (btw. not a good name for list, and hides the builtin of the same name), this might be slow.

Comment: This will loop over the whole list several times to scan for the element; both for the `in` test and the `.remove()` call, leading to quadratic performance degradation. For each new element in the list, you double the work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's a little bit too strong. `in` will only scan the *whole* list (`set`) if it doesn't contain `"311472"`, in which case `remove` isn't even called. I don't think there is quadratic behaviour in the number of elements. Of course, if the lists consist only (or mainly) of `"311472"` elements, there will be quadratic behaviour (but not necessarily because of *scanning*, it's because of *copying*). I pointed that out by saying it will be slow for many repetition. (For the example given by the OP this solution is much faster than yours.)

Comment: In the worst-case scenario, where the second half of a long list of elements contains nothing but `'311472'` that's a lot of scans, each done twice. Since the `.remove()` *already* scans, at least Yann's solution is a little better. :-)

Comment: If there's nothing but that entry, every scan is cheap, but every removal is needlessly expensive, because it keeps rearranging the references in the list. It's the case that favors the rebuilding solution most. .. the second half case makes the scans expensive, so it's likely worse. Sorry for the sloppy reading.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm still not sure what is missing or wrong about my answer. It can be slow in some cases, like I wrote; do you think that sould be empasized more?

Comment: I fear there are *too many* answers here now; perhaps with time more votes will come in but this subject has been hashed out in various ways before.

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about removing every occurence of a given value. `list.remove` already does a scan, so we can call it before even knowing if it can succeed:

```
for sublist in dataSet:
    while True:  # list.remove only removes the first occurence
        try:
            sublist.remove("311472")
        except ValueError, e:
            break  # stop removing, there's no such item in this sublist
```

This is naturally not very efficient if the list that does contain the removed value is large, because we repeated the removal. For the list comprehension solution Martijn Pieters suggested, the bottleneck is instead if the lists that don't contain the removed value are large (since they are rebuilt).

A third solution is to scan the list and move entries, saving the deallocation of entries to the end:

```
def removeAll(lst, item):
    "Like list.remove(), but removes all matching items, without raising ValueError"
    outend=0
    instart=0
    while True:
        try:
            inend=lst.index(item, instart)
        except ValueError, e:
            # We've reached the end of the list
            if outend!=instart:
                # Place remaining items in the correct place and truncate
                lst[outend:]=lst[instart:]
            return

        size=inend-instart
        # Move non-matching items down to replace matching ones
        if size and outend!=instart:
            lst[outend:outend+size]=lst[instart:inend]
        outend+=size
        instart=inend+1  # Skip over the matching entry
```

Pretty horrible example of premature optimization - this takes way too long to write and debug, and has only marginal gains compared to the plain rebuilding (likely none at all, depending on the rest of the program). Actually, come to think of it, I don't think there's any gain because the list slicing itself creates subcopies of the parts we want to keep. I suppose it'll do it you have a high rate of the element you want to remove, a *very* long list, and *really* want the changes done in-place. Altering the original list after the rebuild solution is trivial:

```
lst[:]=[item for item in lst if item!=key]
```

Actually, this just bugged me enough to write another in-place removal variant. This is a somewhat more Pythonic, but still wasteful variant:

```
def removeAll2(lst, remove):
    rem=0
    for idx,value in enumerate(lst):
        if value==remove:
            rem+=1
        elif rem:
            lst[idx-rem]=value
    if rem:
        del lst[-rem:]
```

No exceptions, only one pass over the list, but some clumsy index calculations. This is likely as memory efficient as it gets, though.

Answer (score 0):

we have to remove '311472' from a list

so Try to remove list from that list [list.remove]
ie,

a=[['387230'], ['296163'], ['323434', '311472', '323412', '166282'], ['410119']]

for ina in a:
    for inaina in ina:
        if inaina=="311472":
          ina.remove("311472")
print a