# Removing rows from 2d list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am confused why this short snippet to remove specific pairs from a list fails:

```
g = [[7, 11], [7, 8], [3, 10], [3, 8], [8, 9], [11, 10], [11, 2], 
[11, 9]]
u = 3
g_cpy = g
for e in g_cpy:
    if u == e[0]:
        g.remove(e)
print g
```

It does not remove the entry [3,8], but it does remove [3,10]. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYTHON remove elements from nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220554/python-remove-elements-from-nested-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Use a list comprehension:`g_cpy = [i for i in g if i[0] != u]`

Answer (score 1):

```
g_cpy = g
```

does not create a copy of the list, but just a reference to the same object which you then modify during iteration. Another issue is that repeated `remove` calls are bad in terms of time complexity (each call is `O(N)`). It is better to use a comprehension to build the new list from scratch (overall linear complexity). You can still use that technique *and* mutate the original list by using slice assignment:

```
g[:] = [e for e in g if u != e[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why `[3, 8]` is not deleted is that

You deleted 3th element in array and e will be the 4th element in `g_cpy`.

You already deleted `[3, 10]` in `g_cpy` so `g_cpy`'s 4th element will be `[8, 9]` not `[3, 8]` and this is why `[3, 8]` isn't deleted.

If you copy list like `g_cpy = g` it will just copy memory address. So both of them will point same object. If you delete item in `g` item in `g_cpy` will also deleted.

If you want to avoid this problem, copy list like `g_cpy = g[::]`. It will copy entry object to other memory not just copying memory address.